# Pass component state to redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-day-picker

I am using `react-day-picker` with multi day select http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/selected-multiple.

My question:
Is it possible to pass state of this component:

```
export default class MultiDayPicker extends Component {
state = {
   selectedDays: []
};

handleDayClick = (day, {selected}) => {
   const {selectedDays} = this.state;

if (selected) {
  const selectedIndex = selectedDays.findIndex(selectedDay =>
    DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)
  );

  selectedDays.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
} else {
  selectedDays.push(day);
}
this.setState({selectedDays});
 };

 render() {
return (
  <div>
    <DayPicker
      selectedDays={this.state.selectedDays}
      onDayClick={this.handleDayClick}
    />
  </div>
);
```

to `redux-form` state ??

```
<Field
    name="dates"
    component={MutliDayPicker}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom `MultiDayPicker` component you have to call `redux-form` `input.onChange` method.

So in order to change the `redux-form` state, when your `MultiDayPicker` value is changed, you have to add the following `redux-form` api call in `handleDayClick`:

```
handleDayClick( day, { selected }) => {
  // Rest code here ...

  // Update `redux-form` state
  this.props.input.onChange(selectedDays)
}
```

Also you have to think about the rest `redux-form` input properties and callbacks and decide for which ones to add support. [Here's the full list](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/field.md/#props).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the DayPicker, but i've used DayPickerInput, if you can it instead of DayPicker, you can simply put inside DayPickerInput `inputProps={{...this.props.input}}` as inputProps is defined as additional props to add to the input component.

Redux Form need to find the input name inside of the field you pass from Field to bind the value.

You should also use onDayChange instead of onDayClick i guess.

Code:

```
<DayPickerInput inputProps={{...this.props.input}} onDayChange={this.props.input.onChange} />
```

You can find more information here: [DayPickerInput: inputProps](http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPickerInput#inputProps)